# Obtener valor de variables de un método a otro

Tags: python, flask

espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:

1. Envío `imagen1` desde `formulario1` a una ruta raíz.
2. Capturo código que contiene la `imagen1` y lo almaceno en una variable llamada `barcodeData` (la captura de código se hace sólo una vez).
3. Renombro esa `imagen1` y creo una carpeta nueva. `imagen1` y `carpeta_nueva` las renombro con el mismo código que capturé.
4. La imagen renombrada la muevo a esa nueva carpeta renombrada.
5. Envío `imagen2` desde `formulario2` a `ruta raíz` (tengo que enviar más imágenes desde otros formularios).

El proceso de renombrar imágenes y enviarlas a la carpeta renombrada, creo que sería el mismo como los pasos anteriores, y necesitaría la variable ***`barcodeData`*** para seguir renombrando las demás imágenes que se envían, y variable ***`path`*** de la ruta de la nueva carpeta pero cómo haría para obtener esas variable si las demás imágenes se envía por otras rutas? Adjunto el código. Gracias de antemano.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
 if request.method == 'POST':
  # obtenemos el archivo del input "archivo"
  f = request.files['archivo']

  filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
  _file = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename) # 

  # Guardamos el archivo en el directorio "Archivos PDF"
  f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

  barcodeData = '0094513' **# a través de un proceso capturo el código de la imagen. 0094513 lo pongo de ejemplo - ¿Cómo accedo a variable barcodeData desde función upload_calidad()?**
  carpeta_raiz = 'C:\\app_loteo\\Archivos PDF\\' # carpeta raíz donde llegan todas las imágenes 
  carpeta_nueva_renombrada = "LOT_{}".format(barcodeData) # El resultado es LOT_00123 => ese nombre será el de la carpeta y la imagen
  imagen_renombrada = carpeta_nueva_renombrada + ".jpg" # Nombre de imagen renombrada con su extensión

  for filename in os.listdir(carpeta_raiz):
      if filename in filename.lower():
          try:
            os.rename(carpeta_raiz + filename, carpeta_raiz + imagen_renombrada) # Aquí es donde renombro la imagen
            path = os.path.join(carpeta_raiz, carpeta_nueva_renombrada) **# Esta es la ruta completa de la carpeta nueva renombrada - ¿Cómo accedo a path desde función upload_calidad()?** 
            os.mkdir(path) # creo la carpeta nueva renombrada dentro de la carpeta raíz

            #print("imagen_renombrada:", imagen_renombrada) # LOT_0094513.jpg
            #print("carpeta_nueva_renombrada:", carpeta_nueva_renombrada) # LOT_0094513
            #print("PATH:", path) # C:\app_loteo\Archivos PDF\LOT_0094513
            #print("carpeta_raiz + imagen_renombrada", carpeta_raiz + imagen_renombrada) # C:\app_loteo\Archivos PDF\LOT_0094513.jpg
            
            shutil.move(carpeta_raiz + imagen_renombrada, path + '\\' + imagen_renombrada) # Aquí muevo la imagen renombrada a la carpeta nueva renombrada

          except OSError as error:
                print(error) 
                flash(str(error))

 flash("Capturado código")   
 return redirect(url_for('upload_panel'))

# En esta ruta llegaría otra foto de otro formulario, pero sólo se le cambiaría el nombre a esta foto, y se enviaría a carpeta renombrada.  

@app.route("/calidad")
def upload_calidad():
  return render_template('calidad.html')
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En la función `uploader()` obtengo un código que almaceno en variable la `barcodeData`, y la variable `path` tiene la ruta donde se almacenaría todas las imágenes que se envían. Lo que intento obtener es el valor de esas variables desde la función `upload_calidad()` porque necesitaría renombrar las imágenes con el valor `barcodeData` y almacenarlas la carpeta